# Error trying to connect Expo project to Expo mobile app

Tags: react-native, expo

I was trying to see the final result of the project in React Native with Expo on my Smartphone with the Expo application but, I get the following error:

[image]

**Note:** If you use the Expo web option I can see the result but when I use the Expo mobile application I cannot

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to connect the project with a mobile device.

1. In the device we must have the USB debugging mode.
2. Have the Expo application on the device
3. When executing the project we must enter
   the following command `expo start --localhost --android` or this
   other `npm start --localhost --android`

This may be useful to more than someone.